# Entries with structure:child_ids_for:XXX not bringing up any results

Tags: channel-entries, structure, entryid

I've got an entry tag here that isn't brining in any results whatsoever:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{structure:child_ids_for:43}" fixed_order="{structure:child_ids_for:43}"}
  //Content
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

However, if I call the structure tag and place it between a pair of `<p>` tags:

```
<p>{structure:child_ids_for:43}</p>
```

The result is: `<p>48|44|49|50|51|52|53|54|55</p>` so that is definitely working correctly.

If I then copy the piped ID list and swap `entry_id="{structure:child_ids_for:43}"` for `entry_id="48|44|49|50|51|52|53|54|55"` everything works as intended.

I'm not sure what the difference between those two code segments are. Can anyone help at all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{structure:child_ids_for:XX}` tag is parsed very late, after plugin tags have parsed. In other words, too late to be used as a tag parameter. The channel:entries tag will receive the unparsed structure tag. You will have to use an embed to get around this:

```
{embed="your/embed" entry_ids="{exp:structure:child_ids entry_id='43'}"}
```

And `your/embed` template:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{embed:entry_ids}" fixed_order="{embed:entry_ids}"}
  //Content
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, not sure why I didn't think about using an embed. That said I am still running into the issue. 

`{embed="guidelines/navigation" entry_ids="{structure:child_ids_for:43}"}`

`{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{embed:entry_ids}" fixed_order="{embed:entry_ids}"}`

Calling the {embed:entry_ids} within the embed works perfectly well as before but still no output.

Comment: I think because of the way the global var is parsed it might not even get parsed until after the embed. Luckily, there is the undocumented `{exp:structure:child_ids}` tag that should work since it's not a late-parsed global variable. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for your time, that has worked perfectly.