# Other structure tags not working inside {exp:structure:nav} tag

Tags: structure

I have a scenario where I want 3 levels to show in my main menu, except for one specific level 2 page where I don't want to show its children.

Using hard-coded IDs works fine, eg:
{exp:structure:nav start_from="/" show_depth="3" exclude="100|101|102" }

But when I replace the hard coded IDs with the structure tag that generates these IDs, it doesn't work:
{exp:structure:nav start_from="/" show_depth="3" exclude="{structure:child_ids_for:14}" }

Anyone have any ideas?  I've also tried using snippets and and embedded template and neither work, though a snippet does work when the hard-coded IDs are in the snippet, just not when {structure:child_ids_for:5} is in the snippet.

Here's the code I've tried using embeds:

In the header:
{embed="embeds/main_menu" hideStudentPages="{structure:child_ids_for:14}"}

In the embed:

{exp:structure:nav start_from="/" show_depth="3" include_ul="no" add_level_classes="yes" show_overview="yes" exclude="{embed:hideStudentPages}" }

Thanks in advance,
Justin

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24104/entries-with-structurechild-ids-forxxx-not-bringing-up-any-results/24105#24105

Comment: Sorry Rob, that's not working either in my case, perhaps because I'm using the {structure:child_ids_for:xxx} tag instead of just the {structure:child_ids} tag.   I've updated my entry above with the code I've tried using embeds.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting output from that tag on the embeded template?

Comment: Yes, the output of the tag works just fine - just not inside the {exp:structure:nav} tag.  It's very weird!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `start_from=` tag? Would be a simpler approach than muddying up your templates with embeds.

You'd do something like this for each section:

```
{exp:structure:nav start_from="/about-us" show_depth='1' max_depth='1' has_children_class='yes' show_overview="yes"}
```

Configure your options for however you need the HTML markup to be on the front-end.

You can read about that here:

http://buildwithstructure.com/tags#tag_navigation

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but I need the entire menu to be completely dynamic all the way from the root level, so having to setup a loop for each root level item that generates a child {exp:structure:nav} tag makes it even more complicated than an embed.  Plus, I only need this to happen if the users are logged out.  The {exp:structure:nav start_from="/" show_depth="3" exclude="{structure:child_ids_for:14}" } is tag is really what I need to get working where the {structure:child_ids_for:14} tag parses before the {exp:structure:nav} tag.

Comment: i don't know wether it makes a difference, but have you tried {structure:child_ids_for:14 parse='inward'}"